# How can I write a python scripts using pandas to iterate over Excel .xlsx files with multiple sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, email

I have some Excel .Xlsx files. Each file contains multiple sheets. I have used the following code to read and extract data from the files:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.ExcelFile('my_file.xlsx')
file.sheet_names #Displays the sheet names
df = file.parse('Sheet1') #To parse Sheet1
df.columns #To list columns
```

My interest is the email columns in each sheet. I have been doing this almost manually with the code above. I need a code to automatically iterate over the sheets and extract all emails. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass over all files and all sheets with a for loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

emails = []
files_dir = "/your_path_to_the_xlsx_files"
for file in os.listdir(files_dir):
    excel = pd.ExcelFile(os.path.join(files_dir,file))
    for sheet in excel.sheet_names:
        df = excel.parse(sheet)
        if 'email' not in df.columns:
            continue
        emails.extend(df['email'].tolist())
```

Now you have all the emails in the emails list.

Comment: Forgot to mention that some sheets don't have these 'email' column. I am getting some error

Comment: Just edited, if it doesn't have an email column it continues

Comment: Thanks @Bruno. Can you advise on why am getting this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bongaigaon 500.xls.xlsx'"  I have the file in my /tmp/work path

Comment: Sorry! My fault, I forgot to append the name of the dir along with the file name, see if it works now @urbanmonk

Comment: Working now! Thanks mate